# Terraform and EC2 Provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have been looking around for best practices provisioning a server but have yet to find one. The problem I am trying to solve is configuring an nginx.conf file in the new server setup by Terraform. So I guess my question is: Is Terraform actually used to install packages and configure the server after it is spun up? Or am I supposed to use something else entirely alongside Terraform (i.e Chef)? In the Terraform docs it mentioned removing support for Chef, Puppet and Ansible. It also mentions using the "provisioner" block for this functionality is frowned upon.

I have tried using the Terraform resource `user_data` block and a custom provisioning shell script to do this, but this just seems pretty hacky and difficult to read. I would like to stay away from using a pre-defined AMI as well, which I have also tried.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to tell what the problem you are facing is. But there are two options: AMI baking or bootstrapping.

Comment: The problem I am facing doesn't really relate to having code. It's more of a best practice question. Bootstraping with a shell script after server initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `user_data` is about the best you can do with Terraform for this type of thing. EC2 user-data support is implemented using [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/). There is a [cloud-init Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit/latest/docs) that helps you create user-data scripts and templates, which helps a lot with the readability.

If that isn't to your liking, then you  have to look elsewhere, such as using something like Ansible, or possibly AWS Systems Manager, to install/configure your EC2 instances. However, these would be disconnected from Terraform so you may need to use a `provisioner` to trigger them after a Terraform apply.